# Can selenium automation be used with BS4?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using `selenium` for both automation and scraping. Now I found that it's too slow on some of the sites. If i use `beautifulSoup` then I can scrape them faster but the automation can't be done.

Is there anyway where I can automate the website (button click events etc.) and can also scrape websites with it on `beautifulSoup`?

Can you give me an example of button/search automation with `bs4` + `selenium`?

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Yes you can use both.

Comment: Can you show me any real example? @0m3r

Comment: If your question is *"How can I get the speed of Beautifulsoup and the functionality of Selenium at the same time?"* then the answer is no, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Example*

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup+selenium")
page = Soup(driver.page_source, features='html.parser')
questions = page.select("#questions h3 a[href]")

for question in questions:
    print(question.text.strip())
```

*Or Just*

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/beautifulsoup+selenium'
response = requests.get(url=url)
page = Soup(response.text, features='html.parser')
questions = page.select("#questions h3 a[href]")

for question in questions:
    print(question.text.strip())
```

*Remember to read https://stackoverflow.com/robots.txt*

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely . you can do all the rendering using selenium and pass on the page source to beautifulsoup as follows :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
```

Comment: Will this use the original, static page source or the live DOM?

Comment: @Tomalak the live dom of course , if it passes on the static dom then it's useless and  we should have used requests in the first place .

Comment: Agreed. I just wasn't sure what would happen.

Answer (score 0):

This how-to make it live DOM and loaded js so, Enjoy and Save your time searching, the idea is to get the whole body, if you want also head do replace the body, It will be exactly as selenium get, I hope you like it all.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
dri = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
html = dri.find_element_by_tag_name("body").get_attribute('innerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
```